# Paraphrasing in a Literature Review

Tags: publications, thesis, literature-review

Do you paraphrase in a literature review or just copy stuff and add credits at the end.

for example if I needed to use the following sentence :

> By applying advanced and predictive analytics up front, companies can build R&D plans they can stick to, for shorter lead times and better cost discipline.

Which of the following approaches works best?

> 1.By applying advanced and......  better cost discipline (Mckinsey Global Institute, 2017)

> 2.Using predictive analytics ahead of time can allow companies to create more feasible R&D strategies with shorter lead times and better cost discipline (Mckinsey Global Institute, 2017)

Comment: If you quote, you also have to use quote marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid both plagiarism and copyright issues you can quote short passages and cite the original. You can also paraphrase and cite.

For long passages you have to paraphrase and cite (avoiding copyright issues). But for such short passages, just quote.

Which of your versions is "better" depends on more than you can say here, so I won't suggest more.

---

Note that if you quote (and cite) a *lot* of short phrases you can still run in to copyright issues as (in the US at least) you can't quote so much as to reduce the value of the original.

Comment: +1: With the examples that OP gave, it is definitely better to do a direct quotation of the entire sentence with quotation marks than to attempt a lame paraphrase.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say **neither**. You shouldn't really be "using sentences" out of sources you include in a literature review, you should be writing everything in your own words and then citing for where you got the **concepts and ideas**. You don't just substitute words around and rearrange a sentence and then tack on a citation - that's still not your own writing.

Sometimes your summary of the work is going to be quite similar to the authors' own conclusions in their abstract or discussion, and that's okay, but that doesn't seem like what you're doing here. It seems like you want to take a sentence you've read and insert it into your paper.

If you absolutely must reproduce a sentence, you must use quotes to indicate that it came from another source. It's rarely necessary to do this, unless you are directly discussing what someone else said.

Comment: It depends a bit of field. For fields where 'how' the cited work is written and phrased is important (either in trying to argue the meaning of the other authors words, or perhaps in fields where nicely worded prose is more savored)  I notice that it may be traditional to have direct quotes in papers and books. (history, philosophy, english, languages,...).. In the sciences and engineering fields, I would agree with @Bryan Krause. I cringe when students use 'quotes' of text - its as if they haven't figured out the actual content (which is the important part to the reader in those fields.)

Comment: @Carol Agreed, that's what I meant in my last paragraph mentioning "directly discussing what someone said". Otherwise it's very rare to need to quote.